# "Excel VBA Run Time Error '424' object required" keeps popping up intermittently

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm new to VBA and I keep getting this Error msg pop up every once in awhile on my Spreadsheet. How do I know what's causing this?

Here's the reference to my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim Target As Double
Dim bRun As Boolean
Dim iHour As Integer

'On Error GoTo debugtest

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q1")

'Reset the trigger flag if the last triggered time was yesterday or earlier
If Day(Now()) <> Day(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q3")) Then
    'Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q2") = False
End If

bRun = False
iHour = Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(Time(), "[hh]")
If iHour >= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q9") Or iHour <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q10") Then
    bRun = True
End If
```

What should I do?

Comment: What line does it occur on, when you hit `debug`?

Comment: Is your Outlook running when you encounter this problem?

Comment: not necessarily the reason for your error, but if you are running this code inside "Quotes" worksheet, you can replace `If iHour >= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q9") Or iHour <= ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Quotes").Range("Q10") Then` with `If iHour >= Range("Q9") Or iHour <= Range("Q10") Then`

Comment: when i hit debug it happens on

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Comment: error occurs when outlook is and isn't running